# Using window.hash and wordpress htaccess

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site in which I am displaying posts in a particular section of the website using ajax. I have javascript write the hash tag in via:

`window.location.hash = id;`

This works fine. For example it changes the domain to www.mydomain.com/shop/#147. If someone goes to this link directly, I want wordpress to load the related page instead - eg www.mydomain.com/?p=147, which with my permalinks would convert to something link www.mydomain.com/product/blue-hat. This is the bit I can't work out. Should I be using a Wordpress rewrite rule here? Or should I be adding something to the htaccess file?

Any help in the right direction appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since URL fragments aren't sent to the server, you can't do that.

If you really need to redirect people to ?p=147 you can do so with JavaScript by checking if you have a hash when the page loads. Something along the lines of:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    // Fragment exists
    window.location = "http://your-url-here.com/?p=" + window.location.hash.substring(1);
} else {
    // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```